# Why does extracting a mat-chip-list into its own component change the behavior of mat-label?

Tags: angular-material

If I have an input with a chip list like:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>My fancy label</mat-label>
  <mat-chip-list>
    <mat-chip>some chip</mat-chip>
  </mat-chip-list>
  <input matInput>
</mat-form-field>
```

Then the label is small and pushed up the corner of the form field...

However if I extract that into its own component:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>My fancy label</mat-label>
  <chip></chip>
  <input matInput>
</mat-form-field>
```

Then it looks totally different..  Here is a stackblitz illustrating the problem:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ja1cf2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fform-field-overview-example.html

Why is this happening and how can I make the componentized `chip` version look the same?